# Which is the best way to save data on a mobile device?

Tags: android, sqlite, api, caching, retrofit2

If not want to use `SQLITE DB`, what is the ways can use to save data?

example: Now i'm use `RETROFIT` for `REST API` to fetch Movies of a `server` when I turn-on Internet can show movies, 
but when turn-off internet and restart app will show activity without movies.
I want to make app when turn-off internet show the movies which is loaded before. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/)  Android Volley library has a very elaborate caching mechanism. This is one of the best features of volley. When a request is made through volley first it is checked in the cache. If an appropriate response is present in cache then it is parsed and returned directly to main thread, else a network request is made.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to save your json 'as-is' in file or `SharedPreferences` and get it when your device doesn't have any network.

Also you can try to work with `OkHttp` cache or interceptors https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes